# Get origin or context of a how a post got created and/or updated

Tags: posts, api

Is there an easy way to get the context of how a post (as well as custom post types) got created and/or updated? There are two paths I can think of:

- Via the admin dashboard
- Via the REST API

Is there a way I can find out whether it was via the admin dashboard, the API, or some other path?

I know there is the the `get_current_screen()` method, but I'm not sure if that is a good place to start or not.

Comment: WordPress doesn't keep a record of this on its own, so there's no way to tell for existing posts, if that's what you're asking. I'm curious why you think you need this though?

Comment: It's useful for various logging / historical purposes.